# Differences between aspnetcidev and aspnetvnext?

Tags: asp.net-core, myget

What are the differences between [aspnetcidev](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev) and [aspnetvnext](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext)?

I see that aspnetcidev says "quick builds", but what does this mean?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jan 29, 2016 edit:

This information is now part of the ASP.NET wiki: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/NuGet-feeds

---

The ASP.NET build system uses 3 `myget` feeds for each branch + `nuget.org`.

- `aspnetvolatile<branch>` (`aspnetvolatiledev`/`aspnetvolatilerelease`)
- `aspnetci<branch>` (`aspnetcidev`/`aspnetcirelease`)
- `aspnetvnext` (dev branch)/`aspnetrelease` (release branch)

After each repo under github.com/aspnet builds successfully, each package produced by it is pushed to the corresponding  volatile feed.

After the graph of repos is build, we trigger the [Coherence](https://github.com/aspnet/coherence) build. This build verifies that the packages have matching versions and their references are correct (that they are coherent). Then, it pushes them to `aspnetci<branch>`.

Once the `Coherence` build passes, we run all our tests on the packages in the `aspnetci<branch>` feed. If the tests pass, we sign the packages and ship them to `aspnetvnext` or `aspnetrelease`

So the differences are:

- `aspnetvolatile<branch>`

  - latest packages
  - possible not coherent
  - not tested
  - not signed
  - updated on every checkin
  - mostly used to diagnose build failure
- `aspnetci<branch>`

  - possible not latest
  - coherent
  - not tested
  - not signed
  - updated when all repos build successfully
  - used by our build system
- `aspnetvnext`/ (`aspnetrelease`|`nuget.org`)

  - possible not latest
  - coherent
  - signed
  - tested
  - updated when everything works
  - used for stable packages

Once the `aspnetcirelease` feed is stable, we push the packages from it to `nuget.org`.

Unless you work on developing new features for ASP.NET, I recommend that you use `aspnetvnext` (for dev bits) or `nuget.org` (for release bits). The release feed (`aspnetrelease`) is just a staging feed and it's not always in a good shape.

Edit:

I think it's easier to understand from a table:
[image]

Comment: The information is helpful, but it don't describes why for example **aspnetcidev** has `castle.core.netcore v3.3.4-beta8`, which not exist in **aspnetvnext** and why `CoreCLR v1.0.0-beta6-10444` exists in **aspnetvnext**, but not in **aspnetcidev**. Why **aspnetcidev** has `CultureInfoGenerator v1.0.0-rc1-15822` and `EntityFramework.Commands v7.0.0-rc2-16668m` but "nightly" **aspnetvnext** have `CultureInfoGenerator v1.0.0-rc1-15732` and `EntityFramework.Commands v7.0.0-rc2-16649` (relatively large difference in versions). See https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev and /aspnetvnext

Comment: We clean packages from that feed regulary but if a package doesn't exist anymore in sources or it gets renamed, there might be some left overs

Comment: What about EntityFramework.Commands in version v7.0.0-rc2-16649 on https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext and in version v7.0.0-rc2-16668 on https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev ? Why one have so large difference in version numbers?

Comment: 16649 completed on 28 Dec 15 18:48; 16668 completed on 04 Jan 16 04:36. Between these two builds, EF built successfully every time. Unfortunately, there were some test failures up the stream. If we have any test failures, we don't push *any* package to `aspnetvnext` from `aspnetcidev`. Right now there's a test failure in the `Security` repo.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment. The information displayed in the gallery is wrong. EntityFramework.Commands for example exist in aspnetvnext in versions v7.0.0-rc2-16649, v7.0.0-rc2-16647, v7.0.0-rc2-16647, ..., but in aspnetcidev as v7.0.0-rc2-16668, v7.0.0-rc2-16667, v7.0.0-rc2-16665, v7.0.0-rc2-16664, v7.0.0-rc2-16663, ... In any way one can see that there are no clear rule about the published or removed version in both repositories.

Comment: That's because we don't push every package. Only the latest successful. Also, because of myget space constrains, we only keep the latest 5 (I think?) versions of each package

Comment: It's a little *another problem*, but in my experience the largest problem with different NuGet sources is the usage of locally cached packages. All the packages will be saved in `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages`. If we would build one project which uses `EntityFramework.Commands` using NuGet feed1, it saves the version locally, then if we build another project using **another** NuGet feed2 then Visual Studio will get just **the latest version from cache even if feed2 (which we want to use) don't have it**. It makes many problems and one have to delete full `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages` regular.

Answer (score 2):

I'm abrade that you can get the exact answer on the question only from Microsoft. You can open https://www.myget.org/gallery and filter for "aspnet" for example and will find many other repositories published for different teams.

For me more interesting is the information displayed by .NET Version Manager: `dnvm` (without parameters):

[image]

Thus, for me, the source https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/ (or https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json) is the "official" place for the night builds of ASP.NET 5.

On the other side by filtering of https://www.myget.org/gallery "aspnet" you can see that **aspnetvnext** contains more distinct packages as **aspnetcidev**.

[image]

It's clear that both repositories probably contains different set of packages.

One important example where the repository https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev be used is the new .NET Command Line Interface (.NET CLI) which you find on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli). The new `dotnet` utility uses https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json together with many other sources in https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/NuGet.Config.

**I suppose that AspNetCIDev is the repository of packages required for .NET CLI**. It's the utility, which should replace dnx and dnu in RC2 of ASP.NET 5. See [the post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringTheNewNETDotnetCommandLineInterfaceCLI.aspx), [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/64) and some other.

Comment: `aspnetcidev` is where our coherent but not tested packages go. See my answer for details

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci: Thanks for the info! It seems to me that a lot of different NuGet repositories with the same or not the same packages confuse many users. A little more information about *public* NuGet repositories would be very helpful.