# dnx resolve runtime from global.json

Tags: asp.net, .net, dnx

I am looking at dotnet and DNX to find out whether they are capable of resolving the right runtime version from a global.json and select it automatically or that I have to use `dnvm use xxxxxx` first to select the correct runtime.

I can't find it, but I would expect something like that to happen. 
Is there anyone that can shed some light on this?

Comment: `"sdk"` part of `global.json` can contains `"runtime"`, `"version"` and `"architecture"` which will be used by Visual Studio. See [the post](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DesignNote-19th-Jan-2015), [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/dnx/projects.rst#project-references), [this one](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#the-global-json-file) and [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34794054/315935). I would personally don't switch to `dotnet` utility till RC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sdk` in `global.json` is stricly used by Visual Studio. When you run outside of it, you have to explicitly select the runtime that you want.

Comment: Is it still true that this is only used by visual studio? I can see crashes and other strange behaviour when it's set incorrectly and I run from the command line with the latest `1.0.0-preview2-003131`